# Vibrate on click on widget

Tags: android, button, onclick, widget, vibration

I placed a button in a widget at home screen

I want a method while the user clicked on the widget , the device vibrate.

I know this for normal activities , but what about widgets?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome to have your `AppWidgetProvider` -- or whatever else is responding to the click on your app widget -- to use [the `Vibrator` system service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) to vibrate the device. Just bear in mind that not all devices have a vibration motor, and you need to hold the `VIBRATE` permission to vibrate the device.

Comment: Yes in AppWidgetProvider class I can't use getSystemServise() method !

Comment: @AlizerA: Yes, you can. All of the callbacks into `AppWidgetProvider`, like `onUpdate()`, are passed a `Context`, on which you can call `getSystemService()`.

Comment: @AlizerA: Newcomers to Java should spend time learning Java before getting into Android development. Once you have learned Java, you will be able to understand the following better: call `getSystemService()` on the `Context` passed into your callback method (e.g., `onUpdate()`).